# PowerShell looks like Windows command prompt (cmd)?

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell

I just reinstalled Windows 7, but for some reason the default PowerShell looks like the "cmd.exe" program instead of its usual blue awesomeness.

Anyone know how to fix this? Any way other than digging in and tweaking the colors manually?

Comment: Mine is black if I invoke it from cmd, but blue if I invoke from the menu.  The menu shortcut has the blue background options defined.  Hpw are you starting it?

Comment: Typing "powershell" into the Win7 search box and hitting enter... usually works on other machines. Can't even see it on the menu otherwise.

Comment: So instead of hitting return or clicking it, if you right click it in the search results and go to Properies / Colors, are the colours not set?  The background should be 1,36,86

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you start PowerShell.exe from the run prompt or from a command prompt it will usually end up with the settings of cmd.exe.

Starting it by going through the Start Menu will give you the usually blue look. If you want to just manually set the colors this is what you can set it to for the Screen Background:
Red: 1, Green: 36, Blue: 86.

There are a few scripts out there for customizing the shell through a script or adding it to your profile script, but I find just going to properties of the window suffices for me.